# Laravel - Combining multiple Models to an array

Tags: php, laravel

a few years ago I wrote a PHP web application in a rather procedural way. As this project now gets reactivated and expanded I've made the decision to recode it using Laravel with its MVC structure. As I'm new to Laravel and MVC in general I'm working on converting my procedural approach in an object oriented approach.

After creating Models for each database table I'm faced with several questions:

1. When a page should be loaded that contains data from multiple models what is the best approach? Just call both models, get the data of both Models and send it to the view?
2. When I want to create a view that contains the aggregated data of multiple tables. In the actual version I just created a class that gets the data from both tables, adds some logic and returns the new array to the view. How would this be implemented in laravel? I didn't find some sort of wrapping model. Can you give me a hint how to implement this in laravel?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't overthink things.   If you need two models, grab them and pass them to the view.  If you need to aggregate data, use your existing class, take the resulting array and pass it to the view.   You don't have to change everything to work with laravel or MVC.  The controller should just be the transport layer between your models and your views.

Comment: I highly suggest subscribing to laracasts.com and starting off with their introduction video series. It's probably the best way to learn Laravel.

Comment: For #2, I would create a service class. This can either encapsulate a database query to aggregate the data, or it can encapulate queries for the various models, and functions necessary to build the required output.

Comment: @Polaris: I‘m currently reading the documentation of laravel. As you recommened I will also take a look at these videos. To Devon and fubar: Then I will simply adapt my existing class to work with the Models.

Comment: Just make your next step to get acquainted with Eloquent Relationships. By doing that, most answers to your current several questions will be met regarding this context. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

I would implement an Repository pattern for your problem. Take a look at my Repositories.

https://github.com/avored/ecommerce/tree/master/src/Models/Repository

At this stage my Repository doesn't contain multi table record fetch or store but eventually i will do it. Just for a starting point of view i hope it helps.

Comment: There is a lot of code repetition here, which could be eliminated by using class inheritance.